# “Browse”, “Open file”, “Select files” dialog not working

Tags: windows, windows-10

All of the sudden the method by apps open the "select a file" dialog stopped working. For instance, if I go to https://uploadfiles.io/, clicking on it does nothing, but the drag and drop works.

This is happening for apps as well, for example, I just needed to resync my Google Drive and change the folder location, clicking in "browse" to select a folder does nothing. However, going to Notepad and file > open file works.

I've been searching for a while for the method, .dll, or something that is responsible for this without success. Anyone with a similar issue or more knowledge than what I have can point me in the right direction?

The "Open file" dialog in an application works (Word, Excel, Notepad) but it doesn't work in Google Drive for Desktop, maybe because they use different methods to call it?

Windows 10 64bits, windows insider preview, fast ring

Comment: You may want to consider doing a system restore back to a point before this problem occurred.

Comment: Definitely system restore, as @Twisty noted. Windows 10 has several very good self-repair systems. Start with System Restore..

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. It started somewhere between Friday and today. (Computer was shutdown for two weeks until friday night and before shutting down the problem did not exist.)
I suspect some update.
In addition to the mentioned issue I have trouble downloading files through Chrome.
Edge and IE are downloading fine. Firefox will be installed to test this.
It is consistent which apps are (not) allowed to spawn new windows.
Apps in "Program Files" seem OK while those in "Program Files(x86)" differ.
Of those in the (x86) folder OpenOffice is allowed to open a browse window, Adobe Reader

Comment: Exact same problem since I updated Windows yesterday (to build 16184). I'm running same Windows, same insider preview settings as you. Happens (as in, save file dialog not appearing when it should) in Chrome, Firefox, Adobe Acrobat, among others. Edge, VLC seem to work fine. When I try 'save as' on Notepad++ I can actually see the dialog appear and instantly disappear.

Comment: Henrov is right, x64 apps work normally, so you should upgrade Chrome to x64 (it's the default version now) and that should fix it. But for the Drive app I don't think there is a x64 version…

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem has been completely fixed with the recent update of 16188—Windows appears to have corrected this bug, which it is now clear it was rather than a corruption. Since you are on the fast ring like me, I presume you have also been given this update (if not, seek it out).

From https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/05/04/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-16188-pc-build-15210-mobile/ under 'Changes, improvements, and fixes for PC':

> Localized apps on localized x64 Windows 10 Insider Preview builds will now work. We believe this will also address the issue some Insiders were reporting where the Open and Save dialogs weren’t opening in certain desktop (Win32) apps.